# Getting pointer for first entry in an array

Tags: c#, unsafe-pointers

I want to get pointer of first entry in the array. This is how I tried

```
int[] Results = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

unsafe
{
    int* FirstResult = Results[0];
}
```

Get following compilation  error. Any ideas how to fix it?

> You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a
>   fixed statement initializer

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but its not clear to me :(

Comment: `Results` is not fixed. Unless you fix it, GC might move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error codes are magic to get the answer - search for error code (CS0212 in your case)  and you get explanation with proposed fix in a lot of case.

Search: http://www.bing.com/search?q=CS0212+msdn

Result:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29ak9b70%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Code from the page:

```
   unsafe public void mf()
   {
      // Null-terminated ASCII characters in an sbyte array 
      sbyte[] sbArr1 = new sbyte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x00 };
      sbyte* pAsciiUpper = &sbArr1[0];   // CS0212
      // To resolve this error, delete the previous line and 
      // uncomment the following code:
      // fixed (sbyte* pAsciiUpper = sbArr1)
      // {
      //    String szAsciiUpper = new String(pAsciiUpper);
      // }
   }
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (int* FirstResult = &Results[0])
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message is pretty clear.  You can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx).

```
unsafe static void MyInsaneCode()
{
    int[] Results = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    fixed (int* first = &Results[0]) { /* something */ }
}
```